# Does a quotient map with finite fiber from a Hausdorff space implies its codomain Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology

$\phi:X\to Y$ is a quotient map,$X$ is a hausdorff space, $\forall y\in Y,|\phi^{-1}(y)|<\infty$, does it implies that $Y$ is also an hausdorff space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no.

Say $X=\mathbb{R}\sqcup \mathbb{R}$ (union of two disjoint copies of the real line)

$Y$ be the space obtained by identifying corresponding points of the two copies except the origin. This space $Y$ is called the real line with two origins. Note that the two origins in $Y$ have no disjoint neighborhood (and hence not Hausdorff) but $Y$ was obtained as a quotient space of the Hausdorff space $X$